# How to prove $\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}[4\arctan(e^x)-\pi]\mathrm{d}x={0}$

Tags: calculus

How to prove $$\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}[4\arctan(e^x)-\pi]\mathrm{d}x={0}?$$

I'm trying to prove that the function is *odd*, but I just can't succeed.

Answer (score 5):

To show that the integrand is odd is the right idea. We can prove this by a simple geometrical argument as pointed out by Travis.

Consider a right triangle with legs $1$ and $u$. The accute angles are $\arctan(u)$ and $\arctan(1/u)$ and these must sum up to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ so for $u>0$ we have the identity

$$\arctan(u) + \arctan(1/u) = \frac{\pi}{2} \implies \arctan(u) - \frac{\pi}{4} = -\left(\arctan(1/u) - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

taking $u=e^x$ it follows that $\arctan(e^x) - \frac{\pi}{4}$ is an odd function.

Comment: The identity $\arctan u + \arctan \frac{1}{u} = \frac{\pi}{2}$ (for $u > 0$) also follows from drawing a reference right triangle with leg lengths $1, u$. By definition, the acute angles are $\arctan u$ and $\arctan \frac{1}{u}$, and since the triangle is right, these must add to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @Travis Thats right, did not think about that one. That is a much nicer way to show this imo as it avoids calculus all togeather.

Comment: I'm happy for you just to modify your answer to use the geometric argument instead. In my view, the oddness of the function is anyway the key observation, and the method I pointed out is just a standard trick that helps establish that result.

Comment: @Travis Ok, cool. I replaced my answer by your argument and changed to Community Wiki.

Comment: Cheers, Winther!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is 
to notice that
$\arctan(z)+\arctan(\frac1{z})
=\arctan(\frac{z+\frac1{z}}{1-z\frac1{z}})
=\arctan(\frac{z+\frac1{z}}{0})
=\frac{\pi}{2}
$
so that

$\begin{array}\\
\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}(4\arctan(e^x)-\pi)dx
&=\int^{\pi}_{0}(4\arctan(e^x)-\pi)dx+\int^{0}_{-\pi}(4\arctan(e^x)-\pi)dx\\
&=\int^{\pi}_{0}(4\arctan(e^x)-\pi)dx-\int^{0}_{\pi}(4\arctan(e^{-x})-\pi)dx\\
&=\int^{\pi}_{0}(4\arctan(e^x)-\pi)dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}(4\arctan(e^{-x})-\pi)dx\\
&=\int^{\pi}_{0}(4\arctan(e^x)-\pi+4\arctan(e^{-x})-\pi)dx\\
&=\int^{\pi}_{0}(4(\arctan(e^x)+\arctan(e^{-x}))-2\pi)dx\\
&=\int^{\pi}_{0}(4(\frac{\pi}{2})-2\pi)dx\\
&=0\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: The expression $\frac{z+1/z}{0}$ is undefined.

Comment: But treating it as a limit, $\arctan(z)+\arctan(1/z)=\pi/2$, which is all that is needed.

Comment: Marty, I don't understand why this received a down vote.  Perhaps just write $\arctan(x)+\arctan(1/x)=\pi/2$ to suffice.  So, +1 for the nice solution and also to neutralize the sinister down voter!  Happy Holidays.  - Mark

Comment: I apologize, I skimmed over it too quickly and judged by that small detail. MSE is not allowing me to take back my downvote unless you edit to the question, so if you do that then I will switch my vote to an up vote

Comment: Edit done.  You are forgiven.

Comment: Can you please explain the transition between line 1 and 2 and line 5 and 6

Comment: 1 & 2: replace x with -x. 5 & 6: $e^{-x} = 1/e^x$, so $\arctan{e^x}+\arctan{e^{-x}} = \pi/2$.